# List of interactions of friends with a facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fbconnect

Is there a way to get with FQL or fb.api methods list of interactions of friends inside an application ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so... at least not unless you're using facebook widgets or whatever, in which case maybe, I don't know.  But if it's your app (interactions using code you've written) you'll need to track those interactions on your end I believe.

Comment: guess I've just found a way : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

Comment: Interesting... "interactions of friends inside an application"... I'd reword your question to read "a users facebook wall posts from within an application".  If others read your question the way I did they may not have understood what it was you were looking for.